# C++ vector<T> where T is a struct inside a class

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I have a class that looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
class MyContainer
{

public:

    struct Handle
    {
        public:

            T* Resolve();
    };

private:

    vector<Handle> mHandles;

};
```

It seems like they won't compile the iterator for the handles when I am using:

```
vector<Handle>::iterator iter = mHandles.begin();
```

If I change it to auto it works:

```
auto& iter = mHandles.begin();
```

Am not suppose to use the type explicitly?

Comment: Please show a MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @songyuanyao `mHandles` is private, I think he should try `typename vector<Handle>::iterator`

Comment: @Danh Yes I think you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vector<Handle>::iterator` is a dependent name, hence you must include a `typename` before it, when you use it inside a template function/class

Simply change

```
vector<Handle>::iterator iter = mHandles.begin();
```

to

```
typename vector<Handle>::iterator iter = mHandles.begin();
```

will work.